# Parent process runs twice after receiving signal

Tags: c, operating-system, signals, fork

I wrote a program, where the parent process prints out 5 ( lottery ) numbers, received from the parameter list. Then the child process generates 5 random numbers, and if one of these numbers are equal to the parameters, it sends SIGUSR1, else SIGUSR2 signal to the parent process. 
If i do not use signals, just simply print the answers from the child, the code works fine. But with the signals, the parent process runs twice or at least it's content is printed out twice. Can you please explain this behavior to me? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <signal.h>

void handler(int signumber){
        printf("The child got a hit, my pid: %i\n", getpid());
}

void handler2(int signumber){
        printf("The child had no hit!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGUSR1,handler);
    signal(SIGUSR2,handler2);

    int status, child;
    int num1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    int num2 = atoi(argv[2]);
    int num3 = atoi(argv[3]);
    int num4 = atoi(argv[4]);
    int num5 = atoi(argv[5]);

    if ( num1<0 || num1>45 || num2<0 || num2>45 || num3<0 || num3>45 || num4<0 || num4>45 || num5<0 || num5>45 ){
        perror("We need 5 numbers in range of 0 and 45");
        exit(1);
    }

    child = fork();

    if(child>0){ //parent
        printf("The numbers: %i, %i, %i, %i, %i. my pid: %i \n", num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,getpid());
    } else{
        int rnd,i,isAnyHit;
        isAnyHit = 0;
        srand(time(NULL) * (getpid())); 
        for ( i=0;i<5;i++ ){
            rnd = ((rand()%45)+1);
            if ( rnd == num1 || rnd == num2 || rnd == num3 || rnd == num4 || rnd == num5 ){
                kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
                isAnyHit++;
            }   
        }
        if ( isAnyHit == 0 )
            kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What happens if more than one number matches?  Looks like you will send SIGUSR1 potentially 5 times if all 5 numbers match right?

Comment: It would help if you told us which message gets duplicated. Also, the code would be easier for us to read if you translated the messages to english (what language is that? Hungarian?). One thing that's strange is you don't have your parent wait for the child, so when you get to the kill(getppid(), ...) in the child, chances are your parent has already exited, your process has been inherited by the init process, and you're sending signals to init (hopefully you're not doing this as root!)

Comment: Could be that the parent's printf is being interrupted by a signal and the two concurrent printfs get some data structures confused. If you replace `printf("Szülő: A lottó számok: %i, %i, %i, %i, %i. A pid számom: %i \n", num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,getpid());` with `pause();`, do things work? In general, C signal handlers should do nothing more involved than altering a volatile variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some code changes, and it seems to work for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <unistd.h>     
#include <sys/wait.h>     
#include <errno.h>     
#include <signal.h>    
#include <time.h>    


void handler(int signumber){    
  printf("Got signal %d at %i\n", signumber, getpid());    
}    

int main(int argc, char* argv[])    
{    
  signal(SIGUSR1,handler);    
  signal(SIGUSR2,handler);    

  int status, child;    
  int num1 = atoi(argv[1]);    
  int num2 = atoi(argv[2]);    
  int num3 = atoi(argv[3]);    
  int num4 = atoi(argv[4]);    
  int num5 = atoi(argv[5]);    

  if ( num1<0 || num1>45 || num2<0 || num2>45 || num3<0 || num3>45 || num4<0 || num4>45 || num5<0 || num5>45 ){    
    perror("Invalid numbers\n");    
    exit(1);    
  }    

  child = fork();    

  if(child>0){ //szülő    
    printf("In the parent - child pid is %i, parent pid is %i\n", child, getpid());    
    sleep(1000);    
  } else{    
    printf("In the child - child pid is %i, parent pid is %i\n", getpid(), getppid());    
    int rnd,i,isAnyHit;    
    isAnyHit = 0;    
    srand(time(NULL) * (getpid()));     
    for ( i=0;i<5;i++ ){    
      rnd = ((rand()%45)+1);    
      printf("Checking %i against numbers\n", rnd);    
      if ( rnd == num1 || rnd == num2 || rnd == num3 || rnd == num4 || rnd == num5)){    
        printf("Matched %i\n", rnd);    
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);    
        isAnyHit++;    
      }       
    }    
    if ( isAnyHit == 0 )    
      kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);    
  }    

  printf("PID %i is ending\n", getpid());    
  return 0;     
}
```

Following output:

```
$ ./a.out 1 2 3 4 5
In the parent - child pid is 20401, parent pid is 20400
In the child - child pid is 20401, parent pid is 20400
Checking 6 against numbers
Checking 18 against numbers
Checking 15 against numbers
Checking 42 against numbers
Checking 4 against numbers
Matched 4
PID 20401 is ending
Got signal 10 at 20400
PID 20400 is ending
```

But if 2 numbers match:

```
$ ./a.out 1 2 3 4 5
In the parent - child pid is 20493, parent pid is 20492
In the child - child pid is 20493, parent pid is 20492
Checking 2 against numbers
Matched 2
Checking 5 against numbers
Matched 5
Checking 13 against numbers
Got signal 10 at 20492
Checking 36 against numbers
Checking 19 against numbers
Got signal 10 at 20492
PID 20493 is ending
PID 20492 is ending
```

I get 2 SIGUSR1 (10).

Comment: Your code has the problem that the sleep gets interrupted by a signal, so the parent process will a) sleep the full 1000 seconds if there is no match, b) exit after the first match. Instead of the sleep, better use something like `int rc; while(wait(&rc)==-1) ;` to wait for the child to exit AND handle interruptions to the wait by restarting the syscall.

Comment: Oops. The parent is supposed to get at least a SIGUSR2 if there's no match, so forget about sleeping for 1000 seconds.

Comment: Yeah - the sleep is irrelevant in that case.  I just added it because when I tested, the parent was dying before getting any signals.  I forgot it was seconds and thought it was milliseconds, so I used 1000.

Comment: jesus, i realized it was the /n after i print the numbers in my parent process, if i remove that, just like you did in this version, the buffer is empty, so it won't write it again when reaching another printf, i guess. i will accept this as an answer, at least you helped me to figure it out, thanks all for your time!